# Can I install an 8 GB module in a MacBook that only accepts 4 GB per slot?

Tags: memory, macbook-pro

I recently got this new RAM for my MacBook Pro 13", silver with black keys from early 2011 I believe:

[CORSAIR Model CMSO8GX3M1A1333C9 Laptop Memory - Newegg.com](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16820233216)

Unfortunately it is giving me 3 beeps on startup. Is it incompatible? If so, what should I get that is compatible?

I think the issue may be that it is 8 GB, and Apple lists 4 GB as the max for each RAM module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIRC, 3 beeps on a Macbook is usually a RAM issue.  Installing a module larger than the supported amount almost always causes a system not to boot.  Historically, it would often result in the extra memory just not being detected, but this is often no longer the case as power requirements for DIMMs have increased.

I'd suggest using Crucial.com's memory advisor to identify RAM that is likely to work with your model, or purchasing directly from Apple.